# macOS Monterey "Save As" file naming bug - is there a fix?

Tags: macos, bug, ui, monterey, adobe-photoshop

I've noticed when assigning file names during a "Save As" in Monterey, the text I type gets put in the wrong place. For example, if I am trying to save the file as `img`**.png**, I instead get `i`**.png**`mg`

This means I need to start over naming the file, or select and correct both the beginning and end.

[image]

Are others experiencing this too, and *is there a way to fix it?*

(In addition to this, the Save As dialog window often appears in the bottom left of the screen, and is partially occluded. I have to drag it back to the center before doing anything. But the renaming bug is the bigger nuisance.)

Comment: What _applications_ exhibit this issue? I tested with **Preview** in **macOS Monterey** and it works as one would expect, no issues.

Comment: @user3439894 Interesting. Thanks for that feedback. This is happening consistently in **Adobe Photoshop 2022**. I think I saw it happen elsewhere too. I will make note of any other applications I experience it in.

Comment: @user3439894 I think I run into this as well a few times (and I'm not using Photoshop), thought I just mis-typed/clicked. Will watch for it.

Comment: I have been experiencing weird naming bugs like this as well, but couldn't pin point to a specific application or anything else

Comment: @X_841 I wondered if it might be related to having long file names, or that I always keep my file extensions visible, or maybe something specific to certain applications. These are just ideas, and characteristics I'm paying attention to, hoping to spot a pattern. I haven't spotted any so far. What triggers this bug is currently anyone's guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue for Photoshop when using macOS Monterey. Adobe are working with/waiting for Apple to solve it.

On the [Photoshop/Monterey issues list on the Adobe website](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/kb/photoshop-and-macos-monterey.html#monterey-known-issues), it says the following:

> **Filename error while using Save As**
>
> - Issue: Clicking and typing in the file name field in Save As dialogs, results in jumbled file names
> - Solution: We're investigating the issue with Apple. Stay tuned for updates.

That said, I have experienced this occasionally in other file dialogs (I don't use Photoshop).

The only solution I know of is to press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, and start typing again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm accepting it because it provides as much information as can be known at this time. (Confirms that Adobe is aware of the bug and taking action.) If you find out more with time (like news of a patch), please consider updating your answer with additional info.